# Is there a power series which converges to $f(x) =| x|$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm confused how to solve the following problem:

"Is there a power series which converges to $f(x)$ = $\left| x\right|$ for all $x$?"

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Any power series defines an everywhere-differentiable function, but $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: What happens if you take a power series for $\sqrt x$ and plug in $x^2$?

Comment: A power series that converges to $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't converge for all values of $x$… in particular, it can't converge across the branch cut at $0$.